# In Angular, how to refer to / inject a singleton object in a constant

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, singleton, angular7

I know how to do dependency injection in a component class. i.e.

```
constructor(private staticDataService: StaticDataService)
```

However, in Angular 7, am I able to inject the singleton staticDataService object as an attribute of a constant. i.e.

```
export const myConstant = {
    name: 'ConstA',
    service: staticDataService
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject config values to a module and use this value in your components and services like this. Here is how you define a config where you want to use it:

```
export const YOUR_CONSTANT= new InjectionToken<string>('YOUR_CONSTANT');

export class YourComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(YOUR_CONSTANT) config: any
  ) { }
}
```

And here is a snippet how you can set it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [
    { provide: YOUR_CONSTANT, useValue: 'YOUR_STRING_OR_NUMBER_OR_OBJECT_OR_WHATEVER' },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```